# Java hangs with user input on linux?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I've been trying to do my UW assignment for a few hours now, and I've managed to work my way back to the understanding that user input isn't working. I'm using the scanner class and console.nextLine(); to read in the user's string, but just hangs and won't read in the input when I press enter.

I'm using eclipse, but I tried to do the same thing in netbeans and it still didn't work, and I'm running Linux Mint 11. I've tried restarting my computer, killing the eclipse task and restarting it, and I've asked several other linux users who program, but none of them have a clue. Please help?

Comment: Please post a **minimal, complete** example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: "I've tried restarting my computer, killing the eclipse task and restarting it" - Even without seeing your code I can tell you that its probably you're code that is causing the program to 'hang', not the OS or eclipse.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You haven't provided enough information for anybody to help you; at minimum we need to see the relevant parts of your code.  Depending on the problem, you may need to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  Please also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Easy and very detailed, [step-by-step guide](http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html), which demonstrate how to use Java Scanner class and read user input. Check in your code for **infinite loops**.

If you're completely sure your code is correct, you might have bad environment setup. I am linux user, and I know most distributions come with openJDK, which is more-or-less fine (until you hit Swing). Also sun JDK is now available only from third-party repositories and not in the official ones. Can you post output from the following commands

```
java -version
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $PATH
```

Have you tried to run a HelloWorld program, just to test your environment is correct?
If you can run other projects successfully, it's clear the problem is in your code. If that's the case, provide the parts of your code, that you can think are problematic.

Comment: I'll check the environment setup, but I've done a lot of scanner input before. I checked over it again (not my code, it's a college course assignment that I had to write a manager for). I checked and I am using open jdk, so I'll try installing sun jdk. I've run other programs before with this setup, and I'm pretty sure the code works because everyone else in my class didn't have any trouble while they were using netbeans on windows/macs. Thanks though.

Comment: well, from your comment I think it should be some other reason (than code or openJDK). Maybe Eclipse configuration? Have you tried running it from the command line with java -jar?